# Remove duplication in Ruby map with conditional entries

Tags: ruby, array

I have a nasty (IMO) piece of code for a datatable configuration, how do i best remove the duplication here?

I've tried the obvious things I know (collapsing into one statement and trying inline conditionals) but it isn't working and I can't help thinking there must be a more elegant Ruby way here.

```
if show_status == "true"
  if show_requested_by == "true"
    records.map do |record|
      {
        warning: as_warning(record),
        updated_at: as_time_ago(record.updated_at),
        status: as_status(record.status),
        user: record.user.nil? ? "" : record.user.formal_name,
        manager: record.manager.nil? ? "" : record.manager.formal_name,
        first_date: as_date(record.first_date),
        last_date: as_date(record.last_date),
        days: as_number(record.total_days),
        hours: as_number(record.total_hours),
        units: as_number(record.total_units),
        value: as_number(record.total_value),
        comment: as_comment(record.comment),
        actions: as_actions(record)
      }
    end
  else
    records.map do |record|
      {
        warning: as_warning(record),
        updated_at: as_time_ago(record.updated_at),
        status: as_status(record.status),
        manager: record.manager.nil? ? "" : record.manager.formal_name,
        first_date: as_date(record.first_date),
        last_date: as_date(record.last_date),
        days: as_number(record.total_days),
        hours: as_number(record.total_hours),
        units: as_number(record.total_units),
        value: as_number(record.total_value),
        comment: as_comment(record.comment),
        actions: as_actions(record)
      }
    end
  end
else
  if show_requested_by == "true"
    records.map do |record|
      {
        warning: as_warning(record),
        updated_at: as_time_ago(record.updated_at),
        user: record.user.nil? ? "" : record.user.formal_name,
        manager: record.manager.nil? ? "" : record.manager.formal_name,
        first_date: as_date(record.first_date),
        last_date: as_date(record.last_date),
        days: as_number(record.total_days),
        hours: as_number(record.total_hours),
        units: as_number(record.total_units),
        value: as_number(record.total_value),
        comment: as_comment(record.comment),
        actions: as_actions(record)
      }
    end
  else
    records.map do |record|
      {
        warning: as_warning(record),
        updated_at: as_time_ago(record.updated_at),
        manager: record.manager.nil? ? "" : record.manager.formal_name,
        first_date: as_date(record.first_date),
        last_date: as_date(record.last_date),
        days: as_number(record.total_days),
        hours: as_number(record.total_hours),
        units: as_number(record.total_units),
        value: as_number(record.total_value),
        comment: as_comment(record.comment),
        actions: as_actions(record)
      }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do this would be to inline the conditionals, returning nil when they are not met and use `compact` or `compact!` to remove those entries at the end. Something like:

```
records.map do |record|
  {
    warning: as_warning(record),
    updated_at: as_time_ago(record.updated_at),
    status: show_status == 'true' ? as_status(record.status) : nil,
    user: show_requested_by=='true' ? (record.user.nil? ? "" : record.user.formal_name) : nil,
    manager: record.manager.nil? ? "" : record.manager.formal_name,
    first_date: as_date(record.first_date),
    last_date: as_date(record.last_date),
    days: as_number(record.total_days),
    hours: as_number(record.total_hours),
    units: as_number(record.total_units),
    value: as_number(record.total_value),
    comment: as_comment(record.comment),
    actions: as_actions(record)
  }.compact
}
```

Note: If any of your entries can be nil (and it is important to keep them in the hash) then this won't work.

**Update:** As an alternative that handles nils that are expected you could also go for something like:

```
records.map do |record|
  {
    status: show_status == 'true' ? as_status(record.status) : nil,
    user: show_requested_by=='true' ? (record.user.nil? ? "" : record.user.formal_name) : nil,
  }.compact
  .merge {
    warning: as_warning(record),
    updated_at: as_time_ago(record.updated_at),

    manager: record.manager.nil? ? "" : record.manager.formal_name,
    first_date: as_date(record.first_date),
    last_date: as_date(record.last_date),
    days: as_number(record.total_days),
    hours: as_number(record.total_hours),
    units: as_number(record.total_units),
    value: as_number(record.total_value),
    comment: as_comment(record.comment),
    actions: as_actions(record)
  }
}
```

Although, if the user or status, should be nil they still won't be handled correctly.

Comment: yes, this works nicely, as you say just needed to ensure necessary nils become blanks instead.

Comment: Setting those two values to `nil` will make no difference because attempting to access them if they do not exist will still return `nil`. It only matters if you're either 1) Checking against the array of keys or 2) Changing the hash defaults.

Comment: There are lots of functions that chek for nils, for example in ActiveRecord, `User.assign({login: nil})` is not the same as `User.assign({})`

Answer (score 2):

This is just a rough thought, so it's untested, but here goes:

A vast majority of the hash is the same every time. So, that vast majority can be stuck into a method. There are two fields that are conditionally added to that hash based on their values ('true' or... not). So, we can create a method which takes a `record` as an argument and the two 'true'/not options and generates a hash accordingly:

```
def record_for(record, status: false, requested_by: false)
  record_hash = {
    warning: as_warning(record),
    updated_at: as_time_ago(record.updated_at),
    manager: record.manager.nil? ? "" : record.manager.formal_name,
    first_date: as_date(record.first_date),
    last_date: as_date(record.last_date),
    days: as_number(record.total_days),
    hours: as_number(record.total_hours),
    units: as_number(record.total_units),
    value: as_number(record.total_value),
    comment: as_comment(record.comment),
    actions: as_actions(record)
  }
  record_hash[:status] = as_status(record.status) if status
  record_hash[:user] = record.user.nil? ? "" : record.user.formal_name if requested_by
  record_hash
end
```

Then, all that remains is to convert the strings to booleans:

```
def to_bool(str)
  return true if str == 'true'
  false
end
```

and then iterate over the records:

```
status = to_bool(show_status)
requested_by = to_bool(show_requested_by)

records.map { |r| record_for(r, status: status, requested_by: requested_by) }
```

I'd be happy to go more in depth and test the code if you provided a set of test records that I could use or some larger context this code would run in.